# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_decode() on Cpanel

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter, cpanel

I have **php 5.6** version but still face that error

I'm using Cpanel to run a **codeigniter** project and I got this error:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_decode() in/home/ntn/public_html/application/controllers/Login.php on line 69

I don't know how to solve this error

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: can you show some code part where you are facing issue?(not one line ,some relevant code so that we can understand what's going on? )

Comment: what os are you using in cpanel?? is it ubuntu or windows?

Comment: please post some code and what operating system you're using

Comment: Your PHP installation is missing the JSON extension. See [PHP manual for Installing/Configuring JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/json.setup.php)

Comment: i am using window operating system

Comment: i change php version but miss the selection of json, sorry guys for this. I am really thank full to every one ( Alive to Die ,  Exprator ,  Dre ,  budwiser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you show your code, I cannot help you because ***call to undefined function*** is means it is calling a function which is not defined or mention in your code. its not a cpanel error for sure. its an error in your code

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is a standard PHP function. There is no way the error message could be triggered by a problem in the OP's code.

Comment: sorry i am miss the selection of json in updating php version